# Where is the jeweler in New Tristram?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just started back on Nightmare, and I have all my followers and my upgraded forge right there, in the town center. But I can't find the jeweler... where is he?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He's out in the back, past the Mayor's cart, out toward where the ferryman is.

[image: Minimap]

Answer (score 8):

All the way in the back of the zone, near where you meet Haedrig for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, look at your minimap. From the WP, it will be indicated by a jewel.

Answer (score -3):

There is no jeweler in New Tristram.

Comment: If you return to Act 1 after unlocking the jeweler, or if you are playing on a new character and have unlocked the jeweler on a different character on your account, there will be.